# Possible ways to create custom queries in Corda

Tags: corda

We have a queryablestate for storing some information when the system is initialized, these states are issued once and never consumed

```
class DataState implements LinearState, QueryableState {

    Party partyA;
    Party partyB;
    String partyAId;
    String partyBId;
    String sharedIdentifierNumber;

    DataState(Party partyA, Party partyB, String partyAId, String partyBId, String sharedIdentifierNumber) {
        this.partyA = partyA;
        this.partyB = partyB;
        this.partyAId = partyAId;
        this.partyBId = partyBId;
        this.sharedIdentifierNumber = sharedIdentifierNumber;
    }
}
```

partyA and partyAId must be related to entity A (same for partyB)
some example instances:

```
new DataState(party1, party2, "00001", "12345", "0001")
new DataState(party3, party1, "05432", "00001", "0022")
new DataState(party2, party1, "12345", "00001", "0123")
```

we want to have methods that work like a map:

```
String retrievePartyId(Party party){}
assertTrue(retrievePartyId(party1).equals("00001"))
Party retrieveParty(String partyId){}
assertTrue(retrieveParty("12345").equals(party2))
```

we have already done this by querying all the states with custom field criteria and comparing through iteration on the

```
List<StateAndRef<DataState>>
```

We would like to know if there is some efficient way of doing this, maybe with some custom querycriteria in Corda. We think this is related to `sql column projections`. The query interface returns list of 'states(.getStates())' OR aggregation results '(.getOtherResults())'. We were wondering if it’s possible (or planned) to get a single column from the db and then filter the duplicates through the vault interface, currently we’re doing that in java.

Answer (score 2):

If your states are `QueryableState`s, they can be efficiently queried based on their schema's attributes.

For example, suppose in the CorDapp Example (https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example), I wanted to query the vault for `IOUState`s based on their value and whether I am the lender. I could do this as follows:

```
try {
    Field value = IOUSchemaV1.PersistentIOU.class.getDeclaredField("value");
    Field lender = IOUSchemaV1.PersistentIOU.class.getDeclaredField("lender");

    QueryCriteria valueOver50Criteria = new QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria(greaterThan(value, 50));
    QueryCriteria lenderIsMeCriteria = new QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria(equal(lender, getOurIdentity().getName().toString()));
    QueryCriteria criteria = valueOver50Criteria.and(lenderIsMeCriteria);

    Vault.Page<IOUState> results = getServiceHub().getVaultService().queryBy(IOUState.class, criteria);
    List<StateAndRef<IOUState>> matchingStates = results.getStates();

} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In your case, you would be querying based on the party's ID or the party's name. You would then take the first result and use it to map the party's name to the party's ID, or vice-versa.